# Advantages of implementing a queue via a heap rather than a linked list?

Tags: linked-list, queue, heap

What are the advantages of implementing a queue via a heap rather than a linked list?

All i can think of is that it makes an efficient priority queue, is this correct? What are other advantages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Heap would be useful for out-of-order access.

1. Priority queue (as you mention)
2. Housekeeping (compacting, etc)
3. It might be easier to keep it in good shape if you have multiple consumers chomping at the front of the queue.

It's hard to answer unless we know *why* you are looking at a heap as your preferred data-structure.